# How to add in my xpath a not contains to remove objects that have a img?

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, import, split, google-sheets-formula

This is an example of the sitemap (https://futebolnatv.com.br/jogos-hoje/):

```
<tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <div>
                    <b>
                       <i>
                          <img width="15" height="15" src="https://www.examplestack.com.br/static/paises/1565304830_h1fhplmdg9ahxzhygqvvpg_96x96.png"
                          > Campeonato Alemão - 2ª Divisão </i></b>
               <div>
               <div>
               <style>
               <xyx>
                    <xyx>
                         <b> ONEFOOTBALL (APP) </b>
```

[image]

If I use this XPATH:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://futebolnatv.com.br/jogos-hoje/","//tbody/tr/td//b")
```

I will retrieve two values:

```
Campeonato Alemão - 2ª Divisão
ONEFOOTBALL (APP)
```

The XPATH models that I tried to use to get only the `ONEFOOTBALL (APP)` value were these:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://futebolnatv.com.br/jogos-hoje/","//tbody/tr/td//b[not(contains(#src,'www.'))]")
=IMPORTXML("https://futebolnatv.com.br/jogos-hoje/","//tbody/tr/td//b[not(contains(@i,''))]")
=IMPORTXML("https://futebolnatv.com.br/jogos-hoje/","//tbody/tr/td//b[not(contains(@img,''))]")
```

I can't use the path working with `<xyx>` because every page this value changes, it could be `<xwtrui>` or something else random.

How could I manage to collect this value `ONEFOOTBALL (APP)` on second `<b>` without ending up also taking the value of this first  that in the example is the `Campeonato Alemão - 2ª Divisão`?

Comment: It's going to be difficult to answer without knowing what the url is.

Comment: Hi @JackFleeting i add the url mate, thanks for support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(INDEX(IMPORTHTML(A16, "table", 1),,2), CHAR(10)), " \*|\* |\*", ),,4)
```

[image]